# Preference vs Favoritism

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

Could anyone please explain the subtle difference between **preference** and **favoritism**?

Both of them basically give the same meaning, but there is something more than that in it.
Can someone point that out?

Comment: your _preference_ is the cause of your _favoritsm_.

Comment: No, that's wrong.  It could actually be that the Boss PREFERS people from nation "B", BUT he shows FAVORITISM to people of nation "A".  (In real life, this would be totally commonplace.  For example, the Boss might be bestowing favours on group "A", to impress his upper-boss.)

Comment: An even trickier distinction is the one between _discrimination_ ("the quality or power of finely distinguishing") and _discrimination_ ("prejudiced or prejudicial outlook, action, or treatment").

Answer (score 1):

Favoritism means **bestows favours on**, one group or person over another.

The two words are utterly different and completely unrelated.

Your "preference" simply means which one you **"like more"**. Thus, "I prefer dogs to cats" means exactly "I like dogs more than I like cats."

The recently-coined word favoritism is utterly unrelated to "preference".

Favoritism means (particularly in a work environment) that you give favours to one person over another.  Or, one (say) racial group of people over another racial group of people. Or, perhaps in a family setting, one sibling over another.

Thus for example "The Chairman exhibits favoritism (gives favours to) to people from nation XX over people from nation YY. So, people from XX get all the best promotions and all the best offices, even if they are not performing as well as people from YY."

Comment: In your example, you could substitute *favoritism* with *preference* and have essentially the same meaning.  See 1a and 1c at [TFD:preference](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/preference).

Comment: That's totally, completely, fully incorrect Chris. You are totally wrong. Favoritism is **THE ACT OF DOING FAVOURS** for a certain group of people or one person, over others.  It's just that simple.  "preference" simply means you "like more" A than B.

Comment: I'll take issue with "recently coined" as well: [etyonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=favoritism) has it dating back to 1763.  If you'd rather have [wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prefer), sense 2 may be of interest.  The difference is that "favoritism" is (always) pejorative, while "preference" with more meanings, isn't.

Comment: I could understand Joe, but the two words are not completely unrelated and utterly different. Thanks for your answers guys.